# Can't catch TapAndHoldGesture

Tags: qt, gesture

I `grabGesture()`ed one of my buttons:

```
buttons[0]->grabGesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture);
```

in the constructor, and declared:

```
bool event(QEvent *event);
```

in `protected slots`, and implemented it like this:

```
bool MyClass::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture){
        QGestureEvent *gestevent = static_cast<QGestureEvent *>(event);
        if (QGesture *gest = gestevent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture)){
            QTapAndHoldGesture *tapgest = static_cast<QTapAndHoldGesture *>(gestevent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture));
            cout << "grabbed a gesture event" << endl;
        }
        return true;
    }
    cout << "not a gesture event" << endl;
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

and I keep getting "not a gesture event" printed to screen however I press (normal press / long press / ... )

What I'm trying to do is a long key press (from the keyboard)

It's said in the **Qt Documentation**:

> A gesture could be a particular movement of a mouse, a touch screen
>   action, or a series of events from some other source. The nature of
>   the input, the interpretation of the gesture and the action taken are
>   the choice of the developer.

So I suppose also a keyboard can trigger `QGesture` events.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? I bet the event is posted to button, not MyClass. Have you tried to install and event filter?

Comment: I ended up creating a `Timer` and measuring time from click until release

Comment: Your code should work, untill event is handled at the right place. If you do `buttons[0]->installEventFilter( this )`, where `this` is `MyClass`, then `MyClass` object will receive the event (in `QObject::eventFilter`).

Answer (score 0):

If the class handling the grap (`MyClass`) event is not the class where the gesture is detected on (`QPushButton` assuming `buttons[0]` is a `QPushButton`), then you need and event filter:

```
buttons[0]->grabGesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture);
buttons[0]->installEventFilter( myClass ); // myClass being a MyClass instance
```

Now, `myClass` object will be forwarded all events from `buttons[0]`, this is done using `QObject::eventFilter` virtual function:

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if ( event->type() == QEvent::Gesture && obj == buttons[0] )
    {
        QGestureEvent *gestevent = static_cast<QGestureEvent *>(event);
        if (QGesture *gest = gestevent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture)){
            QTapAndHoldGesture *tapgest = static_cast<QTapAndHoldGesture *>(gestevent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture));
            cout << "grabbed a gesture event" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    // standard event processing
    return Parent::eventFilter(obj, event); // Parent being MyClass parent type, maybe QDialog or QWidget
}
```